# Node.js Socket.io redirect user to other page after joining a room

Tags: jquery, node.js, socket.io

How to redirect after Joining a room

```
socket.on('connect_to_room', function(data, ackno) {
            socket.room_id = data['room'];
            socket.user_name = data['username'];
            socket.join(socket.room_id);
            users.push({ socket : {'socket_id' : socket.id, 'room_id':socket.room_id, 'username': socket.user_name}});
            redirect('/termsandconditions');
        });
```

Load page call

```
 app.get("/termsandconditions", function(req, res){
                res.render(__dirname+ "/termsandconditions.html",{"termdata": terms});
    });
```

Is this Coorect ? What am i missing here?

Comment: What front libraries do you use?

Comment: I'm curious what you're trying to achieve because as soon as you redirect the client, the socket that just joined a room will immediately be disconnected.

Comment: @jfriend00 Would be really helpful if you provide me website link where i can clear my doubts. I am googling it for hours but could not find a solution.

Comment: Clear your doubts about what?  I've simply explained that as soon as the client redirects, the webSocket from the prior page will be disconnected because that page is no longer displayed in the browser (you've redirected to a new page).

Answer (score 1):

You need to send a message through socket.io back to the user. This message you handle client side and there you redirect the user.
Be careful though, redirecting the user like normal HTTP redirect will break the websocket connection. A better alternative is to handle it like a Single Page Application and change state on the client.

Comment: Thanks @emilInferslev Ok. Now I got that I have to redirect user from client side. But is did'nt understand "handle it like a Single Page Application and change state on the client".  Sorry for asking silly questions, am new to Node.js and socket.io.

Comment: There is no silly questions :) Are you familiar with react or AngularJS?

Comment: Okay, with jQuery and JavaScript it would be using that, without moving into another page. Like taking the message from the websocket and `$('body').html("<div>Room " + message + "</div>")`.